# Can I use one registered C2DM account for multiple apps

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I have a platform that is up to 14 branded applications now.  I am
implementing C2DM and am wondering if I need a registered C2DM account
for each application.

I just tried it out in the emulator and got a new registration token
for the second app and sending messages appears to be working fine.

Anyone know if I can just plow forward using a single account?

Is it only the registration key that matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, You will be fine using one account. It is the key that matter's